# Windows cmd or powershell script to start an instance of a program, get its PID and stop it after a time period

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to achieve the following using a command line script in windows:

1. Start an instance of a program (.exe) that launches a GUI (passing also some parameters to the command)
2. Wait a specific amount of time for the program to be executed (e.g. X second)
3. Terminate its execution

It can be the case that **several instances of the program can run in parallel** so what i am searching is a way to be able and terminate the specific instance of the program that was previously launched by the "start" command. A possible way i assume is to be able and get its PID but i am not sure if i can do that when using a simple command line script.

What i have tried is the following:

**A) command line script for program's instance "A"**:

```
Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\XXXX\YYYY.exe" /USER=myUser /PASSWORDD=myPass  /CMDLINEID=winTsk_IntSO_A
timeout 180
taskkill /F /T /IM YYYY.exe /FI "USERNAME eq domain\username"
timeout 30
exit
```

**B) command line script for program's instance "B"**:

```
Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\XXXX\YYYY.exe" /USER=myUser /PASSWORDD=myPass  /CMDLINEID=winTsk_IntSO_B
timeout 180
taskkill /F /T /IM YYYY.exe /FI "USERNAME eq domain\username"
timeout 30
exit
```

But obviously **if i run the two scripts in parallel the taskkill command that is executed first, terminates both instances** (i run them as windows scheduled tasks under a specific user account). The **parameter that identifies uniquely each instance is the /CMDLINEID** but i doubt i can filter the running tasks based on that parameter.

After @filimonic suggestion i am using the following powershell scripts to achieve the objective:

**A) Powershell script for instance "A"**:

```
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start(
    'C:\Program Files (x86)\XXXX\YYYY.exe', 
    '/USER=myUser /PASSWORDD=myPass /CMDLINEID=winTsk_IntSO_A')

Write-Host $process.Id
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

if (-not $process.HasExited) {
    $process.Kill()
}
```

**A) Powershell script for instance "B"**:

```
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start(
'C:\Program Files (x86)\XXXX\YYYY.exe', 
'/USER=myUser /PASSWORDD=myPass /CMDLINEID=winTsk_IntSO_B')

Write-Host $process.Id
Start-Sleep -Seconds 120

if (-not $process.HasExited) {
    //Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | Where-Object { $_.ParentProcessId -eq $ppid } | ForEach-Object { Kill-Tree $_.ProcessId }
    //Stop-Process -Id $ppid
    $process.Kill()
}
```

This is working however i have the following issue:

- YYYY.exe is a GUI application that has a "loading" time ~ 60 seconds
- The first script which has **"10 seconds" wait period** is executed normally and i can see in the task manager that the corresponding "task" is also terminated
- The second script which has **"120 seconds"** wait period is executed normally but **after its execution the "task" in task manager (same PID) remains running**

[image]

Any ideas on how to more effectively terminate YYYY.exe running instance?

Answer (score 1):

From one script:

```
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start('cmd.exe')
$process.Id #PID here
# ... Wait something #
$process.Kill()
```

From second script: *($storedProcessId is somehow stored between scripts)*. You may requre admin permissions

```
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessById($storedProcessId)
$process.Kill()
```

Of course you may use alternaltively more powershell-native way:

```
$process = Start-Process -PassThrough -FileName 'cmd.exe'
```

Of course, there are variants with command line arguments for both ways. See docs for [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start) and [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)

---

So your script will be like that

```
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start(
    'C:\Program Files (x86)\XXXX\YYYY.exe', 
    '/USER=myUser /PASSWORDD=myPass  /CMDLINEID=winTsk_IntSO_A')

Start-Sleep -Seconds 180

if (-not $process.HasExited) {
    $process.Kill()
}
```